# Webpage breaks on WebBrowser but works fine on Internet Explorer

Tags: .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

Any idea why when I go to [this page](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Super-Auto-Window-Regulator-741-713X-/251143955325?) in a .NET winforms application with nothing but a `WebBrowser`, and click the right arrow ">" to go to the next page in the table shown in that page, it stays loading forever. But If I do the same in Internet Explorer 9 and 10, or Chrome it works fine.

I even tried changing [browser emulation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to 9 in an Win 7 machine and to 10 in a Win 8 machine but it keeps doing the same.

Comment: Did you make the eBay page?

Comment: Bizarre... may have something to do with Flash.

Comment: Unless you've changed the registry, the `WebBrowser` control will be stuck in IE7 rendering mode: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enabling [FEATURE_SCRIPTURL_MITIGATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#url_mitigate) in the registry for my application solves this.